# Storage space geth for private network?

Tags: go-ethereum, private-blockchain, clique, geth-clique

Setup a private network with clique at 15 secs block creation. Started with 3 nodes. Then deployed a smart contract (ERC 721) and send two transactions. After about 2 days idling, and no transactions, the node occupied 1.1GB of disk space!

What would be the recommended space for a geth node on a private network? My app will have one ERC721 smart contract and max 5000 transactions.

I understand that about 200GB space is need for a full node to sync with the Mainnet.

Comment: which network are you trying to sync?

Comment: Its a private network.